# C# - Get Property Type from Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an extension method in my ASP.NET MVC app. That extension method looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Metric<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
  var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
  ..
}
```

I call the above using stuff like the following:

```
@Html.Metric(m => m.Flag)
@Html.Metric(m => m.TotalCount)
```

In the above, `Flag` is a `bool?` and `TotalCount` is a `int?`. My question is, in the `Metric` method, how can I detect the type of the property I'm using? The reason I need to know, is, I want to do something like the following pseudocode:

```
var display = "";
if (property is nullable bool)
{
  if (property is null) || (property is false)
  {
    display = "no";
  }
  else
  {
    display = "yes";
  }
}
```

How do I detect what type of property I'm working with?

Thanks!

Comment: `typeof(TProperty)`

Comment: Create an overload without the `TProperty` type parameter and takes an `Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>>` parameter.